# Programmatically triggering the HyperlinkButton navigation

Tags: silverlight, navigation

I'm using the Silverlight 3 [HyperlinkButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.hyperlinkbutton%28VS.95%29.aspx) and I want to programmatically trigger the navigation that normally occurs when the button is clicked. There does not appear to be a public method that supports this.

The **OnClick** method is **protected** so I could inherit from this control to gain access to this method from a custom control but is there a better way to go about this?

Looking at the implementation of the OnClick method using [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) does not give me an obvious hint for a better way and the complexity of the code makes me wonder if there is a good reason for not allowing this event to be triggered programmatically. The lowest level managed code call is to `MS.Internal.XcpImports.NavigateToSafeURINative` and I don't see any public method in the code path that I could use.

Comment: This issue is still there in SL4 (and I suspect SL5). I've updated my answer to include an out of browser solution in addition to the in browser solution I described earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an in browser application, the [HtmlWindow.Navigate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190508%28VS.95%29.aspx) does the trick as follows, relying on a unique target name to make sure it opens in a different tab or window to the current window hosting the silverlight application.

```
var hostingWindow = HtmlPage.Window;
hostingWindow.Navigate(siteHyperLinkbutton.NavigateUri, siteHyperLinkbutton.TargetName);
```

For an out of browser application, the best solution I have found is to derive a very simple custom class from [HyperlinkButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.hyperlinkbutton%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) and implement a public method that in turn invokes the protected [OnClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.hyperlinkbutton.onclick%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method as shown below. This custom class can be declared in XAML with the appropriate NavigateUri and TargetName properties, just like the base HyperlinkButton. I was hoping to avoid creating a custom class by invoking the OnClick method via reflection but this not possible due to the [Silverlight Security Considerations for Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stfy7tfc%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

```
    public class CustomHyperlinkButton : HyperlinkButton
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Exposes the base protected OnClick method as a public method.
        /// </summary>
        public void OnClickPublic()
        {
            OnClick();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please note that this technique might be blocked in current browsers (IE8,9, Firefox 6..9) with Silverlight 4. Only using an `HyperlinkButton`'s `NavigateUri` (data bound) did work in my case, not any other method, including Command.

Comment: Overriding OnClick worked for me in Silverlight with Chrome or IE :)

Answer (score 1):

You could link the button to a Command, then trigger the command anywhere from Code using Command.Execute(). Psuedo code:

**XAML:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="ClassName"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:commands="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation.Commands;assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation">
    <Button commands:Click.Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
</UserControl>
```

**CODE (behind or MVVM):**

```
public class ClassName
{    
    ///Class constructor
    public ClassName()
    {        /// implement the command behaviour as a delegate
    MyCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(
         delegate{ 
                 /// do your OnClick() behaviour implementation here 
                 }
        );
    }

    private DelegateCommand<object> _myCommand;
    public DelegateCommand<object> MyCommand
    {
        get { return _myCommand; }
        set { myCommand=value;
              OnPropertyChanged("MyCommand");}
     }

    /// Another method called from somewhere else in code
    void SomeOtherMethod()
    {
      MyCommand.Execute(null);
    }
}
```

This works particularly well in MVVM world.

Comment: I must be missing something, how does that help me invoke the protected HyperLinkButton.OnClick method?

Comment: OnClick is a code implementation that you are putting in your code-behind right? The same implementation in your OnClick method can be written inside the Command delegate.

Comment: Awesome answer, this helped me out ten-fold. Thanks +1

Comment: Please note that this technique might be blocked in current browsers (IE8,9, Firefox 6..9) with Silverlight 4. Only using an `HyperlinkButton`'s `NavigateUri` (data bound) did work in my case, not any other method. (I'm duplicating this comment from below the other answer)

Comment: @MarkCooper The OnClick method contains the implementation that performs the navigation and it is this code that I wanted to execute. You can subscribe to the Click event in which case your code-behind implementation will be called in addition to the OnClick code path but this does not help trigger the click event.